# preprocessing.scale() giving zero values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to scale one of the feature "Energy" in a set of features f. Before that, I am replacing NaN values with the mean of the feature. Here is the code -

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing

imputer = preprocessing.Imputer(missing_values="NaN", strategy="mean")
energy_array = f["Energy"].as_matrix()
energy_imputed = imputer.fit_transform([energy_array])
print(energy_imputed)
```

This gives me values like -

```
[[-35.25608763 -36.1084797  -33.59742282 -33.50708972 -36.6088168
  -34.910584   -33.05457045 -36.18224291 -51.2727673  -34.12310309
  -30.73922078 -34.73504712 -29.52522131 -35.01537961 -37.0653397
  -31.3648709  -31.72301782 -20.83519558 -21.28122412 -19.61506732
  -16.30594604 -17.00392351 -36.53348958 -39.48780488 -48.17507062
  -40.48660468 -43.35718548 -39.27316566 -33.99082012 -39.26729086
  -33.35805303 -34.6512989  -34.99584325 -31.42133012 -34.93928771
  -37.92288655 -37.22567672 -42.91695745 -38.02082524 -29.1684119]]
```

Now when I try to scale this -

```
energy_scaled = preprocessing.scale(energy_imputed)
print(energy_scaled)
```

I get -

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
]]
```

Why does all the values become zero after scaling?

Comment: According to the part after ```this gives me values like``` you got **1 sample** with **feature-dim 40**. As scale will by default work on [columns](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.scale.html#sklearn.preprocessing.scale), everything gets zero (```If 0, independently standardize each feature```).

Comment: Thanks @sascha. By giving axis=1 as one of the scale parameters, it works well. If you want, do write your work as an answer  to the question.